# Error with OrderBy Object Array Collection Angular Js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The error is in the HTML> Angular says that it can't orderBy because it's not an Array.

HTML:

```
    <div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl2">
    <form>
      Escoje una Opción:
      <input type="radio" ng-model="myOption" value="Ultimas Actualizaciones" />Updates
      <input type="radio" ng-model="myOption" value="Populares de Siempre" />Populares de Siempre
    </form>
    <div>
      <div>
          <h3>{{myOption}}</h3>
          <div>
            <div class="frame" id="basic" >
              <ul class="clearfix" id="clearfixUpdate">
                <li style="font-size:02rem" ng-repeat="comic in comic_data[myOption]">
                   <a ng-href="{{comic.link}}">
                    <img width="162" height="225" alt="{{comic.titulo}}" src="{{comic.imagen}}" />
                    <span  class="titleUp">{{comic.titulo}}</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          <ul class="pages"></ul>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

JS Array Object Collection Example:

```
var dataUpdates = {
  "Ultimas Actualizaciones": {
    "21": {
      "imagen": "imagen.jpg",
      "link": "https://.html",
      "titulo": "Title 21"
    },
    "1": {
      "imagen": "imagen.jpg",
      "link": "https://.html",
      "titulo": "Title 1"
    },
    "2": {
      "imagen": "imagen.jpg",
      "link": "https://.html",
      "titulo": "Title 2"
    }
  },
  "Populares de Siempre": {
    "0": {
      "titulo": "Title 0",
      "imagen": "imagen.jpg",
      "link": "https://.html"
    },
    "1": {
      "titulo": "Title 1",
      "imagen": "imagen.jpg",
      "link": "https://.html"
    }
  }
}
```

Currently the output is something like this:

> Title 1> Title 2 > Title 21

But this is the Behaviour i want to create:

> Title 21 > Title 2 > Title 1

Using OrderBy '-' or Orderby :0:true to set reverse i receive the same error, isNotArray

> ng-repeat="comic in comic_data[myOption] | orderBy:'-'

Comment: What is `comic_data`? The only object you have shown is `dataUpdates` and this is not an array, nor are the values for each key in this object.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom filter and use it instead of `orderBy`. In the filter you can get all the object keys, sort them in the reverse order and return the array on items in the order that needs to be rendered, the implementation of filter may look like as follows:

```
app.filter('objectSortReverse', function () {
    return function (input) {
       return Object.keys(input)
          .map(key => parseInt(key, 10))
          .sort((a, b) => b - a)
          .map(key => input[String(key)]);
    };
});
```

---

Here is a little demo based on the code you shared that should demonstrate the idea:

```js
var app = angular.module('demo', []);

app.controller('myCtrl2', function ($scope) {
  $scope.myOption = 'Ultimas Actualizaciones';
  $scope.comic_data = {
    "Ultimas Actualizaciones": {
      "21": {
        "imagen": "imagen.jpg",
        "link": "https://.html",
        "titulo": "Title 21"
      },
      "1": {
        "imagen": "imagen.jpg",
        "link": "https://.html",
        "titulo": "Title 1"
      },
      "2": {
        "imagen": "imagen.jpg",
        "link": "https://.html",
        "titulo": "Title 2"
      }
    },
    "Populares de Siempre": {
      "0": {
        "titulo": "Title 0",
        "imagen": "imagen.jpg",
        "link": "https://.html"
      },
      "1": {
        "titulo": "Title 1",
        "imagen": "imagen.jpg",
        "link": "https://.html"
      }
    }
  }    
});
app.filter('objectSortReverse', function () {
    return function (input) {
       return Object.keys(input)
          .map(key => parseInt(key, 10))
          .sort((a, b) => b - a)
          .map(key => input[String(key)]);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="demo" ng-controller="myCtrl2">
    <form>
      Escoje una Opción:
      <input type="radio" ng-model="myOption" value="Ultimas Actualizaciones" />Updates
      <input type="radio" ng-model="myOption" value="Populares de Siempre" />Populares de Siempre
    </form>
    <div>
      <div>
          <h3>{{myOption}}</h3>
          <div>
            <div class="frame" id="basic" >
              <ul class="clearfix" id="clearfixUpdate">
                <li style="font-size:01rem" ng-repeat="comic in comic_data[myOption] | objectSortReverse">
                   <a ng-href="{{comic.link}}">
                    <img width="162" height="225" alt="{{comic.titulo}}" src="{{comic.imagen}}" />
                    <span  class="titleUp">{{comic.titulo}}</span>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          <ul class="pages"></ul>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>


</div>
```